# Modifying variable of another method of a class from different class

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, class, methods, attributes

I am new to programming for OOPs, if someone could help me with this code it would be great. The following code is starter code for linked list in python.

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element
```

Can someone help me understand what the **current** variable is doing? Also if there is any reference from where I can get the same in python 3. I can't understand how next can be changed if it belongs to different method of different class.
A similar understanding in python3 would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The current variable is a temporary variable that we are using to traverse the complete linked list and reach the end. We start current variable with the head and then if there is some next we assign the current variable to be that next. For example:

```
element 1: [val : 1, next: element 2]
element 2: [val : 2, next: element 3]
element 3: [val : 3, next: None]
```

Head = element 1
Now we start with `current = element 1`, if `current.next != None`, we assign `current = current.next (element 2)`.
Similarly now that `current = element 2` again we assign `current = current.next (element 3)`.
Now `current = element 3` and `current.next = None`, we would stop and assign `current.next = new_element`.

About how we are changing `next` even though it belongs to a different method of a different class: `next` is not a local variable belonging to the `__init__` function. It is an attribute of the class (specified by the keyword `self`). You can read more about what attributes of a class are and what self signifies [here](https://realpython.com/lessons/class-and-instance-attributes/)